# Configure Rollup (under Vite) build to create separate bundles with theirs assets

Tags: javascript, build, vite, rollupjs

Need your help )
I'm stuck with question - how to configure Rollup build to achieve next build structure.

For example - let's assume that folder structure (it's possible to change it) is:

```
├── src/
│   ├── common-assets/
│   │   └── ...
│   └-- sections/
│       ├── first-section/
│       │   ├── first-app/
│       │   │   ├── app/
│       │   │   │   ├── app-assets/
│       │   │   │   │   └── ...
│       │   │   │   ├── app-components/
│       │   │   │   │   └── ...
│       │   │   │   └-- ...
│       │   │   ├── app.ts
│       │   │   └── index.html
│       │   ├── second-app/
│       │   │   ├── app/
│       │   │       └── ...
│       │   │   ├── app.ts
│       │   │   └──  index.html
│       │   └-- ...
│       ├── second-section/
│       │   ├── first-app/
│       │   │   ├── app/
│       │   │       └── ...
│       │   │   ├── app.ts
│       │   │   ├── index.html
│       │   ├── second-app/
│       │   │   ├── app/
│       │   │       └── ...
│       │   │   ├── app.ts
│       │   │   └── index.html
│       │   └-- ...
│       └-- ...
├── index.html
├── main.ts
├── package.json
└── vite.config.ts
```

Folder `sections` consists of group folders. Each group folder (`first-section`, `second-section`, ...) groups apps of particular kind.

That's what I need to get after build done inside `dist` directory:

```
├── first-section/
│   ├── first-app/
│   │   ├── app-assets/
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── common-assets/
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── bundle.js
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── second-app/
│   │   ├── app-assets/
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── common-assets/
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── bundle.js
│   │   └── index.html
│   └-- ...
├── second-section/
│   ├── first-app/
│   │   ├── app-assets/
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── common-assets/
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── bundle.js
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── second-app/
│   │   ├── app-assets/
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── common-assets/
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── bundle.js
│   │   └── index.html
│   └-- ...
└-- ...
```

So, each `*-section` directory should includes `common-assets` and it's own `index.html` + `bundle.js` files.
Each app (`first-app`, `second-app`, ...) will be used and served as separate application (with it's own store/routing/etc).

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling as well to do this with vite. I think vite is not intended for this usecase. There is a workaround I did, that maybe you can adapt to your purposes.

Basically, I have two html files I want to fill: `app1.html` and `app2.html`.

Each app's source code is in its own directory: `src/app1` and `src/app2`.

The apps share very few resources, but I still want to build those two in one go.

My structure is as follows:

```
├── app1.html
├── app2.html
├── src
│   ├── app1
│   │   ├── App.svelte
│   │   ├── components
│   │   │   └── Component.svelte
│   │   └── main.ts
│   ├── app2
│   │   ├── App.svelte
│   │   ├── components
│   │   │   └── Component.svelte
│   │   └── main.ts
│   ├── shared
│   │   ├── global.css
│   │   └── shared.ts
│   └── vite-env.d.ts
├── svelte.config.js
├── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.node.json
└── vite.config.ts
```

You can see there are two separate apps: `src/app1` and `src/app2` with similar structure.

I could not find a way to build them separately using only one call to `defineConfig`, so basically I build the apps separately, using the `emptyOutDir: false`. This way I won't lose one build when doing the other.

Then, I created some scripts in my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vite build",
    "build:app1": "vite build",
    "build:app2": "vite build",
    "build:all": "pnpm build:app1 && pnpm build:app2",
    ...
  },
```

The good part about this, is that from `vite.config.ts` i can access the name of the command using `process.env.npm_lifecycle_event`. It will be set to `build:app1` if I do `pnpm build:app1`. I can use this to choose which part of the source code to build.

This is my `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { svelte } from "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte";

const buildScript = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

const app = buildScript.includes(":") ? buildScript.split(":")[1] : "app1";

const buildConfig = {
  rootHtml: `./${app}.html`,
  entryFileNames: `${app}/${app}.js`,
  assetFileNames: `${app}/${app}.[ext]`,
};

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: { app: buildConfig.rootHtml },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: buildConfig.entryFileNames,
        assetFileNames: buildConfig.assetFileNames,
      },
    },
    emptyOutDir: false,
  },
  server: { open: buildConfig.rootHtml },
});
```

After running `pnpm build:all`, the dist folder should look like this:

```
dist
├── app1
│   ├── app1.js
│   └── app1.css
├── app1.html
├── app2
│   ├── app2.js
│   └── app2.css
└── app2.html
```

I hope this helps. I may try to use rollup instead of vite to see if I can do it more elegantly, but this workaround helped me achieve my goal.